# How can i generate JSON String form LinkedHashMap<Integer,String>

Tags: json

How can i generate JSON String Form linkedHashMap.

map contains (1,aaa) (2,bbb), (3,ccc)... from this i need to generate Json string

{ {id:1,text:"aaa"},{id:2,text:"bbb"},{id:3,text:"ccc"},...}

Please any one can help me to fix this.

Comment: Your JSON string is incorrect. Did you mean [ {id:1,text:"aaa"},{id:2,text:"bbb"},{id:3,text:"ccc"},...]  ( "[" instead of "{" )?

Answer (score 0):

In javascript a map is acutally pretty much the same as a classical object:

```
{ "1": "aaa", "2":"bbb","3":"ccc",... }
```

I am not 100% sure you can use numbers as keys...

an alternative would be to use a structure like this and have an array of objects:

```
[ {id:1,text:"aaa"},{id:2,text:"bbb"},{id:3,text:"ccc"},... ]
```

or to be more in the spirit of a map, you should name the fields "map-like":

```
[ {key:1,value:"aaa"},{key:2,value:"bbb"},{key:3,value:"ccc"},... ]
```

All 3 are valid json/javascript forms, which one suits you best depends on what you actually want to use it for.